# Firebase cloud function error in updating collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

i am trying to use cloud function such that when a document is created in collection 'RecruiterJobs' the cloud function is triggered and updates the value in documents of a collection 'CollegeCode' and according to condition  either a single document or all the documens of collection is to be updated ,
here is the index.js part of my cloud functions

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin= require('firebase-admin');


exports.TPOjobcount = functions.firestore
    .document('Recruiter/{JobId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      const newValue = snap.data();
      const colleges = newValue.Colleges
      if (colleges === 'All'){
       const docRef = admin.firestore().collection('CollegeCode')
                    docRef.get().then(snapshot=>{
                        snapshot.forEach(doc=>{
                            docRef.ref.set({
                                OffCampusJobs:firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
                                JobRecruiter: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(newValue.CompanyName)
                            },{merge:true}).catch(() => null)
                        })
                    }).catch(() => null)
      }
```

when i am trying to run firebase deploy --only functions  , it gives error of

```
 19:39  error    Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return
  21:29  warning  Avoid nesting promises                      promise/no-nesting
  30:62  error    Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return
  32:17  warning  Avoid nesting promises                      promise/no-nesting
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to correctly return the chain of the different promises returned by the asynchronous Firestore methods.

This is of utmost importance when dealing with asynchronous methods in Cloud Functions. For more details, I would suggest you watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/

---

Also, since you want to execute several calls to the [`set()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#set) method in parallel, you need to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

---

The following should do the trick. **However**, since you do `docRef.ref.set(...)` with `docRef` being a `CollectionReference`, it is not clear to which  document(s) you exactly want to write (a `CollectionReference` does not have a `ref` property). Please adapt your question as needed, in case there is the need for fine tuning.

```
exports.TPOjobcount = functions.firestore
    .document('RecruiterJobs/{JobId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {

        const newValue = snap.data();
        const colleges = newValue.Colleges

        if (colleges === 'All') {
            const colRef = admin.firestore().collection('CollegeCode');
            return colRef.get()
                .then(snapshot => {
                    const promises = [];
                    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                        promises.push(doc.ref.set({
                            OffCampusJobs: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
                            JobRecruiter: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(newValue.CompanyName)
                        }, { merge: true }))
                    });
                    return Promise.all(promises);
                })
        }
        else {
            const colRef = admin.firestore().collection('CollegeCode')
            return colRef.where('StudentCode', '==', colleges).get().then(snapshot => {
                return snapshot.docs[0].ref.set({
                    OffCampusJobs: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
                    JobRecruiter: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(newValue.CompanyName)
                }, { merge: true });
            });
        }

    });
```